# How to get the column name with the its count distinct in flask-sqlalchemy?

Tags: mysql, sql, flask-sqlalchemy

I don't know how to select the column value with its count in flask-sqlalchemy.

I've used `SELECT browser, COUNT(browser) FROM visitor_stats GROUP BY browser;` to get the `browser name` column with its count using group by in SQL, but I cannot transform it into flask-sqlalchemy function.

Comment: I would start by giving the `COUNT(browser)` an alias like `SELECT browser, COUNT(browser) as browser_count FROM visitor_stats GROUP BY browser;`

Comment: The proposed duplicate is for SQLAlchemy; for Flask-SQLAlchemy you cangenerally  substitute `db` for `sqlalchemy` in imports etc.